# Upgrading windows 8 to 8.1 on vhd

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, windows-8.1, boot-to-vhd

Here is my situation: Wanted to try windows 8.1 out so I wanted to use a vhd. The first problem I had was that running the windows installer specific to windows 8.1 refuses to install it to a vhd, but running the windows 8 installer allows it to be installed to a vhd. So I installed just windows 8 to my vhd, and attempted to install the 8.1 update from within the vhd but it refuses to install 8.1 because it says it cant be installed to a vhd, and I have searched a bit and found Im not the only one with this problem. So then I tried to make a system image with windows of the working windows 8 vhd in an attempt to clone this installation to a usb hdd, then boot from this and attempt to install windows 8.1 on this usb hdd. I found a tool called clonezilla but I could not figure out how to mount a vhd in clonezilla or find the system image I previously made. Anyone have any suggestions for how I can clone my vhd to a usb hdd, or is it not going to be possible to boot from the usb hdd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [**can't update** Windows 8 to 8.1 when booted from a VHD](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Explorer-Hang-81-upgrades-Optimal-Battery-Conditioning?format=html5#time=16m54s). You only see this error:

[image]

The only way would be to use a 2nd Windows 8 Pro (or Server 2012), activate Hyper-V, create a Win8 VM, use the VHD, boot the VM and update from 8 to 8.1 in the VM and later use the VHD again for native boot after upgrading to 8.1.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I must make another Windows 8 vhd, boot it and then create a vm from the original  vhd and then from the vm I will be able to update to 8.1?

Comment: you need no other VHD. Starting with Win8 you can use the same VHD for a VM and native boot. Use the 8.0 VHD in a VM and upgrade here to 8.1.